# NDSolve There are fewer dependent variables, {V[S,t]}, than equation

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve the BlackScholes PDE for Barrier option. It works fine for european barrier, but errors out on american boundary condition

```
sol1 = NDSolve[{D[V[S, t], t] + r*S*D[V[S, t], S] + 
1/2 sigma^2 S^2 D[V[S, t], {S, 2}] - r V[S, t] == 0, 
  V[S, t] ==    Piecewise[{{0, S >= 120}, {Max[S - K, 0], S < 120}}]},V, {S, 0.1,   1000}, {t, 0, T}]
```

If I change the boundary condition to capital "T", it works fine

```
V[S, T] ==    Piecewise[{{0, S >= 120}, {Max[S - K, 0], S < 120}}]}
```

If it's for any time t, then it complains about fewer dependent variables. Is there any other way to specify boundary condition for 2 variables? It seems a simple issue, but can't find anything in mathematica documentation!

Comment: For those who are not familiar with the Black-Scholes equation with the barrier option, can you either edit your question to include the PDEs and the boundary conditions you're trying to implement, or link to a description of same?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: The code as first written does not include a boundary condition but instead an equation defining `V` for all `S` and `t`, which eliminates it as a dependent variable; hence, the error.  Changing `t` to `T` turns the second equation into a bouncary condition, and all is well.  You need a boundary condition in `t` too, something like `V[S,0] == 0`.  Also, note that `sigma` and `K` are undefined.  Although it does not matter here, it is bad practice to begin variable names with  capital letters, because Mathematica functions also begin  with capital letters.

Comment: Yes I realize the problem. I basically want to specify boundary condition as V[S,T] = Max(S-K,0) for S<120 and V[S,t] = 0 for S>=120. Not sure how to write this in pde format for dsolve

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think this method worked, but still NDSolve gives an unstable solution.

```
barriersolution = 
 NDSolve[{D[V[S, t], t] + r*S*D[V[S, t], S] + 
     1/2 sigma^2 S^2 D[V[S, t], {S, 2}] - r V[S, t] == 0, 
   DirichletCondition[V[S, t] == 1, (S >= 100 && t == 1)], 
   DirichletCondition[V[S, t] == 0, ( S < 100 && t == 1)]}, 
  V, {S, 10, 200}, {t, 0, 1}, PrecisionGoal -> 10]
```

It's not at all stable for `V[100,0]` ranging from 0.43 to 0.56 for slight change of `S` boundaries. I was trying to price binary digitals with a pde where payoff is 1 if `Spot > 100` at expiry. Probably I should supply the mesh along with the pde problem to get a stable solution. Maybe a mesh which is finer near expiry time and very sparse before expiry time.